# Encryption using cryptojs AES algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I done encryption in java like below, but the same code I need in javascript because same formate am using to decryption
or else anyother option encryption in javascript and decryption in java using cryptionjs.

```
static char[] pass={'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d'};
static String alg="PBEWithMD5AndDES";
private static final byte[] SALT = { (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33,(byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x10, };

public static String encrypt(String property) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(alg);
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(pass));
    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance(alg);
    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
    return base64Encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(property.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}

private static String base64Encode(byte[] bytes) {
    return new BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Check this example https://codepen.io/gabrielizalo/pen/oLzaqx

Comment: I am unable to implement above code javascript, i tried and i got errors like size length, badpadding exceptions. I could not find the exact functions in javascript

Comment: Please include your attempt at the problem.  Voting to close as too broad.